# How do I make a div tag appear and blur everything else until timeout or clicking X

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make the background blur (in css, html and JS) and a `<div>` tag appears? i am building a site and want to play a small loading animation at the start, but I do not know how to make the `<div>` tag appear and blur the background.
Thank you,

Ring Games

Comment: Sorry, the `div` tag appears over the background

Comment: Hint: If you want to fix a part of your question, there's a handy `edit` function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I giving you a simple example where you can blur div by button press. I think it will help you.

```html
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio necessitatibus id nam numquam aliquid dolore ipsam eum. Id sed alias placeat expedita! Libero tempore nobis asperiores temporibus adipisci earum quibusdam.
  </div>

  <button class="toggle"> Toggle Blur </button>
```

```css
.content {
      width: 300px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      padding: 10px; 
    }

    .blur {
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);  
    }
```

You have to add Jquery first

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function(){

      $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $(".content").toggleClass("blur");
      });

    })
```

See it on Codepen
https://codepen.io/biswassuman/pen/BaowLRm

#### Full Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    .content {
      width: 300px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      padding: 10px; 
    }

    .blur {
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);  
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio necessitatibus id nam numquam aliquid dolore ipsam eum. Id sed alias placeat expedita! Libero tempore nobis asperiores temporibus adipisci earum quibusdam.
  </div>

  <button class="toggle"> Toggle Blur </button>

  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready( function(){

      $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $(".content").toggleClass("blur");
      });

    })

  </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can JQuery be used in `<script>` tags?

Comment: @RingGamesCompany Once you include jQuery, you can.
See https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp on how to get started.

Comment: @RingGamesCompany add this code in the head of `HTML` Document `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @RingGamesCompany I am adding full HTML document in answer, that's why you can understand.

Comment: @SumanBiswas Thank you very much. It works! Thank you, I have marked the answer witht the tick, and also upvoted your comment, thank you

Comment: @RingGamesCompany Glad to help you. Thank you for upvote my answer.